# NoMethodError in ProfilesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an associated form for Profiles but for some reason when I hit the submit button, I'm getting a NoMethodError which doesn't make sense to me as my code is exactly the same as a tutorial I'm following... unless the tutorial is outdated..
`def create`
`@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`
`@profile = @user.profiles.create(params[:profile])`
`redirect_to user_path(@user)`
`end`

Anyone know why I'm getting the noname errors?
The form that belongs to the controller is below:
https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel/blob/master/app/views/users/show.html.erb
**EDIT 1:** Fixed! The following code isn't displaying the profile data at http://localhost:3000/users/2 (which is profile#show) though: `<%= @user.profile.first_name %>`
Here's my current profiles#show
`def show`
`@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`
`@profile = @user.profile.find(params[:id])`
 
    `end`
**EDIT 2:** I've updated my github repository at https://github.com/imjp/SuperModel

Comment: you can try using create_profile! (with the ! bang version) to check if any exception is raised. maybe a validation error or attr_accessible/protected set on Profile model.

Comment: Naw, it doesn't work. I've pasted my show action above.. Any idea what might be causing the action to throw up this error? `undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: there's no need to to an additional find to profile, just @profile = @user.profile

Comment: `def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = @user.profile 
 end` Doesn't work though.. i still get the same error

Comment: then the profile isn't getting created properly, this is another matter though. when you create the profile, try using the bang version like I wrote above and see if there are errors and that the record is getting created in database properly, check logs.

Comment: Hey I've added the bang and it displays the profile data now! But when I refresh the page it disappears.. makes no sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why @user.profiles? try @user.profile (singular)

Comment: I tried that too but that one throws this error: `undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: because probably User has_one profile the constructor is different, try @user.create_profile(params[:profile])

Comment: Thanks man! I'm not getting errors anymore :) I can't seem to access the stored variables now though. Check my edited version

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass` because a User with that id could not be found. You're probably sending a wrong param or something. How does a URL for your show action look like?

edit:

change your create method in users_controller.rb to this

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.build_profile

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

After you've changed this, change your form in *app/views/users/show.html.erb* to this

```
<h3>Add Profile</h3>
<%= form_for([@user, @user.profile]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :picture %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :picture %>
</div>
<div class="field"> 
    <%= f.radio_button(:sex, "male") %>
    <%= f.label(:sex, "Male") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:sex, "female") %>
    <%= f.label(:sex, "Female") %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div> 
<% end %>
```

and it will work. Your user-profile association was not built.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( User has_one :profile   Profile belongs_to :user

Comment: Hey thanks for the update man! I feel we're getting there. I'm getting the following error now `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` at Showing c:/rails/supermodel/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #20 raised:

Comment: I've just downloaded your github code, changed form in view and edited my form and it works here. I suppose you were changing something in your local repo, so do this `git reset --hard dbdc1b6`, this will reset you to your public commit. Then change your code in controller and view and it MUST work :D

Comment: I fixed it :D I just went through the **getting started** guide from rubyonrails.org which has the similar structure as what i'm trying to achieve, but in plural.. so i singularized it and it works fien now.. weird lol